# how to parse this by simple html dom parser in php

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

```
<div id="productDetails" class="tabContent active details">
<span>
<b>Case Size:</b>
</span>
44mm
<br>

<span>
<b>Case Thickness:</b>
</span>
13mm
<br>

<span>
<b>Water Resistant:</b>
</span>
5 ATM
<br>

<span>
<b>Brand:</b>
</span>
Fossil
<br>

<span>
<b>Warranty:</b>
</span>
11-year limited
<br>

<span>
<b>Origin:</b>
</span>
Imported
<br>


</div>
```

How can I get data like 44mm, fossil, etc. by DOM parser in PHP?

the data i can get easily by

`$data=$html->find('div#productDetails',0)->innertext;`

`var_dump($data);`

but i want to break it in meta_key and meta_value for my sql table...
 i can get the `meta_key` by

`$meta_key=$html->find('div#productDetails span',0)->innertext;`

but the meta value related to it????

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You can use Zend_Dom. It's very good and you can use selectors like in jquery. Here is the [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.dom.html)

Comment: well I tried this                                          $data=$html->find('/span/br');
$data= explode("\n", $data[0]->plaintext);
var_dump(trim($data[0]));

Comment: how did you _parse_ the dom, why are you using regular expressions, even though you parse the dom, just traverse it

Comment: by traversing I am getting output as null.

Comment: The values I am trying to parse is out of span tag,then how come traverse

Comment: @rituraj - Code in comments is unreadable, feel free to edit the question and add further details there (I've done it for you this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard, really... [just google, and click this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), you now know how to parse a DOM, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) you can see what methods you can use to select all elements of interest, iterate the DOM, get its contents and what have you...

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlString);
$spans = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');
for ($i=0, $j = count($spans); $i < $j; $i++)
{
    echo $spans[$i]->childNodes[0]->nodeValue.' - '.$spans[$i]->parentNode->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

That seems to be what you're after, if I'm not mistaken. This is just off the top of my head, but I think this should output something like:

```
Case Size: - 44mm
Case Thickness: - 13mm
```

**UPDATE:**
Here's a tested solution, that returns the desired result, if I'm not mistaken:

```
$str = "<div id='productDetails' class='tabContent active details'>
            <span>
                <b>Case Size:</b>
            </span>
            44mm
                        <br>

            <span>
                <b>Case Thickness:</b>
            </span>
            13mm
                        <br>

            <span>
                <b>Water Resistant:</b>
            </span>
            5 ATM
                        <br>

            <span>
                <b>Brand:</b>
            </span>
            Fossil
                        <br>

            <span>
                <b>Warranty:</b>
            </span>
            11-year limited
                        <br>

            <span>
                <b>Origin:</b>
            </span>
            Imported
                        <br>
    </div>";
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($str);
$txt = implode('',explode("\n",$DOM->textContent));
preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9].*?\:).*?([0-9a-z]+)/im',$txt,$matches);
//or if you don't want to include the colon in your match:
preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9][^:]*).*?([0-9a-z]+)/im',$txt,$matches);
for($i = 0, $j = count($matches[1]);$i<$j;$i++)
{
    $matches[1][$i] = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$matches[1][$i]);
    $matches[2][$i] = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$matches[2][$i]);
}
$result = array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]);
var_dump($result);
//result:
array(6) {
    ["Case Size:"]=> "44mm"
    ["Case Thickness:"]=> "13mm"
    ["Water Resistant:"]=> "5"
    ["ATM Brand:"]=> "Fossil"
    ["Warranty:"]=> "11"
    ["year limited Origin:"]=> "Imported"
}
```

To insert this in your DB:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO your_db.your_table (meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (:key, :value)');
    $stmt->execute(array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
}
```

*Edit*
To capture the `11-year limit` substring entirely, you'll need to edit the code above like so:

```
//replace $txt = implode('',explode("\n",$DOM->textContent));etc... by:
$txt = $DOM->textContent;//leave line-feeds
preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9][^:]*)[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9][^\n]+)/im',$txt,$matches);
for($i = 0, $j = count($matches[1]);$i<$j;$i++)
{
    $matches[1][$i] = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$matches[1][$i]);
    $matches[2][$i] = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$matches[2][$i]);
}
$matches[2] = array_map('trim',$matches[2]);//remove trailing spaces
$result = array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]);
var_dump($result);
```

The output is:

```
array(6) {
  ["Case Size"]=> "44mm"
  ["Case Thickness"]=> "13mm"
  ["Water Resistant"]=> "5 ATM"
  ["Brand"]=> "Fossil"
  ["Warranty"]=> "11-year limited"
  ["Origin"]=> "Imported"
}
```

Comment: well i see all this but could not understand that clearly as i could...Hope this time i could.

Comment: @down-voter: I don't mind down-votes, as long as I know why. Who knows, I might learn a thing or two along the way

Comment: I can get that data by simply: $data=$html->find('div#productDetails',0)->innertext;   but i want to break the data as meta_key and meta_value for mysql table

Comment: @rituraj, call me a bit thick if you like, but am I right in saying there's a colon that separates the key and value, and a line-break to separate the key-value pairs?

Comment: @ellas you are absolutely right dear,,,but how come i insert meta_value seperately for each meta_key...it is out of tag.

Comment: @rituraj: I've updated my answer, with a tested example, [see it in action here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a686603a4e235d2afdcbcfc5f8c6404055b15980)

Comment: array(6) {
  ["Case Size"]=>
  string(4) "44mm"
  ["Case Thickness"]=>
  string(4) "13mm"
  ["Water Resistant"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["ATM Brand"]=>
  string(6) "Fossil"
  ["Warranty"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["year limited Origin"]=>
  string(8) "Imported"
} please see that for "warranty"=>only 11 is coming ,,rest is going to "origin" meta_key.

Comment: @ellas by the way thanks a lot for your valuable feedbacks...hope to be in touch

Comment: @ellas i know dear,but i m new to it and my reputation is below 15,sory,as i reached above par,i will surely upvote urs...thanks

Comment: @rituraj: That's not a problem here, you can vote on every answer to your own questions, regardless of your reputation. But I would like to know: is my answer working for you, or are there some other things you're having difficulties with? Oh, and if you're inserting this data into a DB, please do use `PDO`, and not `mysql_*` (in case you were using `mysql_*` ATM -> it's being deprecated)

Comment: @ellas thanks buddy,its working,i need some customisation that i will surely do by myself...thanks a lot,,plzz let me know about the upvote,,i am unable to do,it responds that i must have 15 rep. to do so..sorry:-(

Comment: @rituraj: Just had a look, you're right: upvotes do require a minimum of 15 rep. By accepting this answer you received an additional 2 rep, so you should be granted the upvote-privilege now. Good luck with customizing the code, and happy coding ;-)

Comment: @ellas:Thanks buddy...will diturb you more in the future,,;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the span tag using the set_callback Api

Try this

```
$url = "";

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$html->set_callback('my_callback');

$elem = $html->find('div[id=productDetails]');

$product_details = array();
$attrib = array( 1 => 'size', 2 => 'thickness', 3 => 'wr', 4 => 'brand', 5 => 'warranty', 6 => 'orgin' );

$attrib_string = strip_tags($elem[0]->innertext);
$attrib_arr = explode('        ',$attrib_string); // hope this can help you for every product 
// Remove Empty Values
$attrib_arr = array_filter($attrib_arr);

$i = 1;
foreach($attrib_arr as $temp)
{
   $product_details[$attrib[$i]] = $temp;
$i++;
}

print_r($product_details);

// remove span tag inside div
function my_callback($element) {
if($element->tag == 'span'){  $element->outertext = ""; }
}
```

Comment: I edit my code, You need to make sure that Everytime explode() function should work for every product